# Backbone.js: correct way to close View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

***What I have:***

I can navigate from one view to another. Moreover, the sequence of such navigations can be long enough. So its not acceptable to hide the first view when I navigate from it to the second (because its no guarantee that I'll ever return from the second view to the first).

***What a problem:***

I don't know how to close backbone's View.

***Question***

What is the correct way to close backbone's View?

EDIT:
the problem is that I can't remove view even after
view.remove();
view.unbind();

Comment: `view.remove() ` doesn't work for you?

Comment: What code do you already have and what did you try?

Comment: I save all route history in my router. And I use this.$el.hide() inside view when I need to go to the next view

Comment: May be the best solution will be to store stack of views instead stack of routes, and show/hide the views when it is needed?

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450271/backbone-js-view-history-best-practice. It's more wide question

Comment: remove doesn't work for me as I expect. Seems it works in the same way as view.$el.hide(): view is hidding but it leave eclipsed background and adopt all click events

Comment: yes, because you probably created a zombie view, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

It's simple like doing

```
view.remove()
```

but beware, even if you call `view.remove()` some bindings may remain referenced (even if you don't see the view anymore), this causes the famous "Zombie View" problem.

There is a great post from Derick Bailey about dealing with "Zombie Views" and about the proper ways of closing views and doing view transitions:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/

Comment: I've read your post. And what? In it you remove your view via view.close(). See EDIT section of my question

Comment: The article you refer to is dated, This zombie problem has been fixed since 0.9.9 with the `listenTo` and `stopListening` pattern and shouldn't be a problem anymore.

Comment: The existence of Zombie Views barely depends on your implementation so it isn't something that "can be fixed". Even if they added those functions to get rid of some boilerplate, without a proper "close" implementation you can still create zombie views.

Comment: @NickoleAbs yes, in that most (which isn't mine) there is a custom functions which does all the view closing logic to you, if you call `view.remove()` your view will be removed. This is the correct view to close a view.